# How to use pjsip in flutter?

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, pjsip

Hai I created flutter_module with the command `flutter create -t flutter_module`.
Now I want to use pjsip in my flutter project.I provided flutter_pjsip and url in dependencies.But When I run `flutter pub get` in terminal it says ,

```
Because flutter_module depends on flutter_pjsip from unknown source "url", version solving failed
```

Can anyone please help me to integrate pjsip into vs code flutter project.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show me the entire pubspec